# How to determine which account sent an extrinsic from substrate block data?

Tags: extrinsic, xcm, data-analytics

Could anyone help me understand how one reads from a substrate chain the account that sent an extrinsic?

For example take this Kusama [`xcmpallet.reserve_transfer_assets`](https://kusama.subscan.io/extrinsic/15047372-3) extrinsic sent by address *JHz14NmqDJZ3vGwWNZAAezW4KsiSofw8ptoeg3LtksDqU4L*

I can parse from the XCM message the account address it's being sent to from the `beneficiary` section but in the XCM message I am unable to see which account sent the extrinsic.

Does anyone know where the sender address is being read from?

For context I am using [py-substrate-interface](https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface) to read data from the block chain using [`substrate.get_block(block_hash=block_hash)`](https://polkascan.github.io/py-substrate-interface/#substrateinterface.SubstrateInterface.get_block) and then parsing the block for extrinsic data.

Comment: A block's extrinsic will always contain a signer, as long as it has a signature, something along the lines of [this](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/sp_runtime/generic/struct.UncheckedExtrinsic.html). This is probably some weird behavior about the python interface, hiding the extrinsic author somewhere hard to find. What is the exact output of this `get_block`?

Answer (score 3):

The example in the py-substrate-interface README shows exactly how to do this.

https://github.com/polkascan/py-substrate-interface/tree/v1.3.3#method-1-access-serialized-value

```python
# Set block_hash to None for chaintip
block_hash = "0x51d15792ff3c5ee9c6b24ddccd95b377d5cccc759b8e76e5de9250cf58225087"

# Retrieve extrinsics in block
result = substrate.get_block(block_hash=block_hash)

for extrinsic in result['extrinsics']:

    if 'address' in extrinsic.value:
        signed_by_address = extrinsic.value['address']
    else:
        signed_by_address = None
```

Comment: Thanks @joepetrowski!!